# Python HTTP Server not working when connecting to 0.0.0.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, localhost

When I run:

```
python -m http.server
```

I see the message `Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...`

When I navigate there in my browser I see "This site can’t be reached".

I am using:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.6
- The unix-style console emulator [cmder](http://cmder.net/) (build on top of ConEmu).

Any ideas about what the problem could be? I've tried specifying different ports but there is no change.

Comment: go to  `http://127.0.0.1:8000` ... `0.0.0.0` means any available interface ... it does not mean the literal ip `0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` ... `0.0.0.0` means any available interface ... it does not mean the literal ip `0.0.0.0`